# Rewrite this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation
$$y'(t)=\alpha y(t)-\beta y^2(t), y(0)=N_0$$
and need to use $z(t)=\frac1{y(t)}$ to rewrite it as 
$$z'(t)=-\alpha z(t)+\beta$$
I've literally tried every standard algebra trick to work this and can't get it. Can anyone see a trick or technique that I might be missing that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the chain rule, we have:

$$y=\frac{1}{z}\quad\rightarrow\quad y' = -\frac{1}{z^2}z'$$

and:

$$y' = \alpha y - \beta y^2 \quad\rightarrow\quad
-\frac{1}{z^2}z' = \alpha\frac{1}{z}-\beta\frac{1}{z^2}$$

See it now?